# C# Listbox and PictureBox connected

Tags: c#, listbox, picturebox

I created listbox with 20 names for example:

1. John
2. Tom
3. Alex
4. etc.

but I don't know how to connect this with picture box.

If I select for example John from the listbox, in the picture box will appear his picture.

(pictures named same as listbox items)

How can I do that?

Please help me, I couldn't find answer, I'm beginner..

Comment: A `Dictionary<String, BitmapImage>` can help you.

Comment: Read up on events and event handlers for `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speking about WPF you can do something like this:

```
        <ComboBox Name="cmbConector">
            <ComboBoxItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image></Image><TextBlock Text="Jonh"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ComboBoxItem>
           <ComboBoxItem>
           ....
           </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

You can put all what you want in a "ComboBoxItem" (or ListBox).

Comment: No :( I'm using windows form application in vsb

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the pictures address for each items in listbox.
For example:

```
array({'John','C:\\John.jpg'},{'Tom','C:\\Tom.jpg'})
```

Second, when index item changed, you should set image property address.
For example:

```
picturebox1.image = image.fromfile("{ Picture Address }");
```